# compare a timestamp index with a fixed date in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataframe with timestamp index. I want to delete all rows with timestamp index after `2001-01-01`. After some googling, I get to this:

```
df.index[1].date() < pd.datetime.strptime('20010101', "%Y%m%d").date())
```

It works fine as it shows the first index is less than `2001-01-01`.

So I happily applied to:

```
df.index.date() < pd.datetime.strptime('20010101', "%Y%m%d").date()
```

and got this instead:

> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.

to give you a sense of what the index looks like, when I just enter:

```
df.index[1]
```

it returns:

```
Timestamp('1964-01-03 00:00:00')
```

Comment: can you add a sample of the code you are working on? Like variable initializing, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are setting your index correctly.

You can subset your dataframe using dates.
https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_time_series_basics.html

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['2014-05-01 18:47:05.069722', '2014-05-01 18:47:05.119994', '2014-05-02 18:47:05.178768', '2014-05-02 18:47:05.230071', '2014-05-02 18:47:05.230071', '2014-05-02 18:47:05.280592', '2014-05-03 18:47:05.332662', '2014-05-03 18:47:05.385109', '2014-05-04 18:47:05.436523', '2014-05-04 18:47:05.486877'], 
        'battle_deaths': [34, 25, 26, 15, 15, 14, 26, 25, 62, 41]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'battle_deaths'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.index = df['date']
df.drop(['date'], axis = 1, inplace = True)

df2 = df['2014-05-03':]
```

Comment: df2 = df['2014-05-03':] this line of code is exactly what i am looking for!